# Jquery .toggle does not work on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, toggle

I'm trying to toggle a div on click via jQuery.

But somehow on my live site it does not work at all.
I tried `.toggle;` `hasClass` `.addClass` `.removeClass` in `if/else;` also `.show/.hide` on `if/else` and so on.

But somehow the content does not get displayed or cannot be hidden.

Here is my working fiddle with the segment DOM of the livesite:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x2dkaym3/)

```
$(".jsselect").click(function() {
   var popup = $(this).next(".popup_select");
   if (popup.hasClass('showit')) {
     popup.removeClass('showit');
   } else {
     popup.addClass('showit');
   }
});
```

Here is my livesite: [Livesite](http://clipdisplayserver.de/wordpress/produkte/konfigurator/)

Comment: Have you checked debugger console on your livesite? Any errors there?

Comment: Just FYI you can shorten the click handler to just `$(this).next('.popup_select').toggleClass('showit');`

Comment: Hey there, I just figured it out. I added the same .js file twice in my source... Yes, seriously. Thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Well,
sometimes you just need to go to bed and figure out, that you've added the same script.js twice - so the code did execute twice.

Well, screw me then ;)
Thank you all so much!